# PHP file_get_contents sends to same port when changed with about 1 minute

Tags: php, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I have a PHP script that calls our server running IIS 10 on different specified ports.  It is PHP version 7.3.12.  I am running this script from a shelled out windows process by doing "php.exe script.php", not from a browser request.  When I change ports within about a minute, it is keeps sending to the first port specified.

As an example, if I run the script 3 times doing these 3 iterations in a row:

```
$result = file_get_contents('https://example.com:6447/token', false, $context);
$result = file_get_contents('https://example.com:6453/token', false, $context);
$result = file_get_contents('https://example.com:6447/token', false, $context);
```

and check the logs, they all are logged under 6447.

I tried the exact same thing with postman and it works as expected.  the first and third ones log under 6447 and the second under 6453.

I then tried copying the script and running them separately and it still posts to the wrong port.

Is there something I need to do to close the connection or something.  I am stumped.

Comment: All I can think of is a broken proxy somewhere. I don't think this is a PHP issue.

Comment: Does it also happen if you use `curl`?

Comment: I was thinking of trying curl.  Never used it before.  Everything I have done I have been able to get by using file_get_contents.  I am going to set it up and see what happens.

Comment: I tried curl and same issue.  I then tried an example script from my PC and it worked fine.   My php version is 7.4.2.  I then tried it from the command line on the original server that is having the issue and it also does not switch ports.  After the first try, it returns fast, like it is already connected.  If I do it on my pc, it runs the same each time and works.

Comment: I suspect it's some kind of firewall issue on the server.

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding timeouts and that did not help either.  Both servers are internal although only the one I am calling is exposed to the internet.  Maybe their bat loopback settings are somehow doing this.  I think I will try setting it up on another PC inside the network and see if the issue is still there.  Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: No idea, I've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: It seems like the firewall is caching the destination but when a new connection is made, it ignores the destination port and just uses the same cached port. Seems totally broken to me.

Comment: But it's not a PHP programming problem.

Comment: I agree.  I did one last test and moved the copy of php back to my pc and it worked fine, so must be some firewall issue.  Not sure how to resolve this.  I might just create a php relay to an outside server and see if that works.  Thank you for your suggestions and feel free to offer more.

Comment: I tested this with postman and it does the same thing, so it is not php code or implementation for sure.  I will keep this open and post what the issue is if/when we get it resolved as I cannot find anything similar on the web.

Comment: The question says it works OK with postman. What changed?

Comment: I was not thinking it had to do with internal vs external and thought it was a php issue when I initially wrote the question.  I tried postman externally and it worked originally.  Later, after I figured out it was internal vs external, I tried postman internally and it failed as well.  Hope this clarifies it.  Internally, the call ignores the port specified after the first try for about a minute from both php and postman.  Externally, it works every time.

Comment: That adds more support to the conjecture that there's a network firewall doing this.

Comment: I tried doing a tracert on the server that is both the IIS server as well as the one that I tested with (same machine) it only does one hop.  I was expecting it to hit something along the way but that makes me think it is either some firewall/AV on the server or else some iis configuration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we solved it.  Here are the notes:

- The scripts were calling the DNS FQDN “example.com”. Inside “Domain Controller” DNS translated it to “xxx.xxx.100.10”
- xxx.xxx.100.10 is on the Citrix Netscaler. Intended during development to funnel requests to the IIS Server IP address and mitigate the attack surface until Windows Firewall settings were done.
- The setting was left because no issues were occurring at the time.
- The Netscaler was doing too good of a job by holding the source record & port constant even if a new port came from the same source “too soon”
- Changing the Internal DNS record to point “example.com” to IIS Server IP Address made the requests go direct, eliminating the issue

Thank you to Barmar for working through this with me and pointing me in the right direction.